# How to persist a connection pool for asyncpg and utilise it in Databases wrapper?

Tags: python, fastapi, asyncpg

As per FastApi documentation, I'm using the [Databases](https://github.com/encode/databases) wrapper and Sqlalchemy Core to do async operations on the postgres database.

I have come across an issue where the connection gets closed in the middle of operation. As it turns out it is an [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56922665/connection-was-closed-in-the-middle-of-operation-when-accesing-database-using-py) with `asyncpg` and can be resolved by using a pool.

However I'm not using asyncpg directly, but use the Database wrapper as it was recommended by FastAPI. How can I create a pool like this:

```
await asyncpg.create_pool(database="dbname", 
    user="username", 
    password="dbpw",
    max_inactive_connection_lifetime=3)
```

and utilise it within the databases wrapper?

```
import databases
from sqlalchemy import MetaData

db = databases.Database(settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
metadata = MetaData(schema='main')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under hood [database.connect](https://github.com/encode/databases/blob/master/databases/backends/postgres.py#L60) uses `asyncpg.create_pool`, your SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI already has connection vars, you could also add additional connection options:

```
db = databases.Database(settings.SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, max_inactive_connection_lifetime=3)
```

They will be passed to `asyncpg.create_pool` on connection.